# GWT /SmartGWT gradle compile error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: warningThreshold

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Below is the error when compile the gwt/smartGWT using gwt-gradle in mac env plugin de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6

Any idea to avoid below error ,GWT version is 2.8.2

```
[ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: warningThreshold
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$1.<init>(JdtCompiler.java:652)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.getStandardCompilerOptions(JdtCompiler.java:650)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.getCompilerOptions(JdtCompiler.java:682)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:1038)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:325)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:548)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:479)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:465)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:423)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:222)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:202)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:143)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:204)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:155)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:144)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:118)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:125)
```

Answer (score 2):

This error means that either you have multiple copies of GWT on your classpath, or you have latest GWT and a version of the JDT that doesn't match, so the field `warningThreshold` is missing. Double check your dependencies that GWT 2.8.2 is the only version of GWT present, or double check that no other jars contain a copy of the `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.impl.CompilerOptions` class, which happens to be of a different version than the JDT that GWT needs.